# How I can include python Window or frame in html using Web2py?

Tags: python, html, ubuntu, web2py

I am using web2py framework for my project and Ubuntu 12.04 operating system iI have created python window that i want to add/include/merge in html page

How I can do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean rendering web2py form helpers in a python application.

https://code.google.com/p/gui2py/wiki/Web2pyExample

I haven't tested it myself yet, I've been playing on using it for a project I'm working on.